# calcular el factorial y el exponente respectivamente de todos los números de dos listas

Tags: python

Escribir un programa que devuelva el factorial y el exponente respectivamente de todos los números de dos listas. ingresar por teclado los elementos de cada lista. al inicio preguntar cuantos elementos se ingresaran en cada lista.

Hola! llevo esto hecho esto en python:

```
lista1=[] 
lista2=[]

numero=int(input("Cuantos numeros ingresara a cada lista?:")) lista1=int(input("Ingresa los numeros para lista 1:")) 
lista2=int(input("Ingresa los numeros para lista 2:"))

for x in range (lista1): 
factorial=x*x-1 
lista1.append(input("lista 1:")) 
lista2.append(input("lista 2:"))
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y agrega lo que has intentado, de otro modo tu pregunta tal ve termine cerrada

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo, el problema está en el bucle en el que intentas conseguir el factorial.

**FACTORIAL:**

Conseguir el factorial de un número es sencillo, solo tenemos que obtener el producto de todos los enteros positivos que son menores que él. Es decir, si tenemos un número que es igual a 5, el factorial será 120.

**5 x 4 = 20**

**20 x 3 = 60**

**60 x 2 = 120**

**120 x 1 = 120**

**PROBLEMA:**

El bucle que has publicado está mal desde su primera línea:

`for x in range (lista1):` te dará error ya que la lista es una sucesión de valores, es decir accedes al valor, para recorrer la **LONGITUD** de la lista debes hacer `for x in range(len(lista1)):`

Donde la función len() devolverá un entero (`int`) que podrá ser evaluado por la función range() y así iterar una vez por cada elemento de la lista, y donde `x` contendrá el índice del elemento.

La identación también está mal, pero eso puede ser porque hayas editado mal la pregunta, si no es así, debes añadir el bloque que está dentro del for, con una identación de 4 espacios.

```
for x in range(len(lista1)): 
    factorial=x*x-1 
    lista1.append(input("lista 1:")) 
    lista2.append(input("lista 2:"))
```

`lista1.append(input("lista 1:")) 
 lista2.append(input("lista 2:"))`

En estas dos líneas lo que estás haciendo es añadir más elementos a la lista a través de la función append(), más input(), que es la entrada estándar, por lo que añadirías `n` elementos más a la lista, en función de la longitud de esta.

**Posible solución:**

```
for i in range(len(lista1)):
    for k in range(l1[i], 1, -1):
        if k == l1[i]:
            continue
        l1[i] = l1[i] * k
```

En este bloque de código:

Recorremos la longitud de la lista `for i in range(len(lista1)):`

Sobre el primer valor de lista1, recorremos su rango, desde el final(-1) hasta que `k=1` `for k in range(l1[i], 1, -1):`

Si el valor de `k` es igual al valor de `l[i]` hacemos un `continue` para que el bucle continúe iterando sin realizar el resto de sentencias dentro del propio bucle.

```
if k == l1[i]:
    continue
```

Y por último, como las listas son mutables, es decir, podemos modificar los valores que contenga, el tamaño de lista, etc..

Pues vamos modificando el valor hasta que el bucle termine. `l1[i] = l1[i] * k`

**Salida sobre una lista de dos posiciones con un valor de 5 en cada posición**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.